# Вопросительные слова русского языка

Tags: падежи

В учебнике 3 класса было сказано, что "куда" - это вопрос родительного падежа. Я засомневался в этом. Пример: "Я поеду в Москву" (куда?). Это же винительный падеж. Я прав?
С уважением, Владимир.

Comment: Я думаю, Вы правы.

Comment: Нужно различать грамматический и смыслововй вопрос. Куда? - смысловой, во что? - грамматический.

Comment: в родительном падеже нет вопроса КУДА есть вопрос КОГО и ЧЕГО можно в уме поставить слово без (кого?) брата тоже самое можно сказать со словом НЕТ нет (кого?)брата


Comment: в уме слово нет

Comment: ой в винительном падеже нет вопроса КУДА есть вопрос КОГО ЧТО виню (кого)пса.Можно необязательно ВИНЮ просто если  со словом нельзя поставить ВИНЮ это не винительный

Answer (score 2):

Да, это никак не родтельный.

"Куда?" предполагает только два варианта ответа "во что/кого?" и "на что/кого?". (Не сочтите за намек на что-то неприличное). В обоих случаях - падеж винительный.
Родительный может появиться только при ответе на вопрос "откуда?" - "Из кого/чего?", "С кого/чего?"
Возможно, этим и объясняется ошибка в учебнике.

Рассуждений по поводу различия "смыслового" и "грамматического" вопроса в данной связи, простите, не понял. Как ни крути, родительный там не появляется. Ни в смысловом отношении, ни в грамматическом.

Answer (score 0):

Существительные в родительном падеже, выступающие в роли обстоятельств, имеют вопросы Где? Откуда? ("...на мутном небе мгла носилась"). В вашем примере явно правило и ответ взяты из другой темы "Винительный падеж". Но опечаткой это назвать трудно:слишком она большая.

Comment: на небе - это не винительный, это предложный!